# In PolymerJs, value change not reflecting on html

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

H,

I was trying to hide/unhide div based on variable value. Below is my code.

```
  <div id="content" hidden$="{{ _hideDiv( myValue ) }}"></div>

  <paper-icon-button id="button" on-tap="_myValue" icon="create" hidden$="{{ _hideButtons( myValue, readonly ) }}">
  </paper-icon-button>

  <paper-input id="input" value="{{ value }}" hidden$="{{ _hideButtons( myValue, readonly ) }}">
  </paper-input>
```

by using `myValue` property i am trying to hide / unhide div and buttons. But whenever i change the myValue it not reflecting on html.

In console.log i could see the changed new value but in html i dont see the change. Could someone please help me and i m not sure why it not reflecting ?

```
  onInit( value ) {
    if ( someCondition i check here ) {
      this.set( 'myValue', false );   // THIS CHANGE NOT REFLECTING
    } else {
      this.set( 'myValue', true );  // THIS CHANGE NOT REFLECTING
    }
  }

  _dataChanged( data ) {
    this.onInit( data );
    this.set( 'myValue', false );
  }

  _myValue() {
    this.set( 'myValue', !this.myValue );
  }

  _hideButtons( isActive, readonly ) {
    return myVal === true && readonly === false;
   // myVal is not defined !! Is it this.myValue or isActive ?
  }

  _hideDiv( myVal ) {
    return myVal === false;
  }
```

_myValue method change reflects but on onInit method i am setting value on element initialization that is not reflecting.

Comment: everything looks fine. this is a right approach and I don't see anything wrong. So the problem will be somewhere else out of the code you posted propably. Are you using polymer version 1 or 2 ? you specified both tags in question....  is _hideDiv function called? what is the value of myVal when its called. If it is type of string then myVal === false will always be false.

Comment: using polymer2, myVal is Boolean type.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to illustrate your code at Codepen: It's working as it should work. You have some syntax errors. Here below `Run Code Snipped` will demonstrate your example or, I will try to make it more compact with my own modification with this :
[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/ZwExjy?editors=1010)

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  
class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }
      static get properties() { return {
        myValue:{
          type:Boolean,
          value:false
        },
        readonly:{
          type:Boolean,
          value:false
        }} }

onInit( value ) {
    if ( this.myValue ) {
      this.set( 'myValue', false );   // THIS CHANGE NOT REFLECTING
    } else {
      this.set( 'myValue', true );  // THIS CHANGE NOT REFLECTING
    }
  }

  _dataChanged( data ) {
    this.onInit( data );
    this.set( 'myValue', false );
  }

  _myValue() {
    this.set( 'myValue', !this.myValue );
    console.log(this.myValue)
  }

  _hideButtons( isActive, readonly ) {
    console.log(isActive, readonly )
    return isActive=== true && readonly === false;
  }

  _hideDiv( myVal ) {
    return myVal === false;
  }
     

 }
customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
   
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  
</head>

<body>
<x-foo></x-foo>
<dom-module id="x-foo">
<template>
<style>

</style>
  <div id="content" hidden$="{{ _hideDiv( myValue ) }}">Div Element</div>

  <paper-icon-button id="button" on-tap="_myValue" icon="create" hidden$="{{ _hideButtons( myValue, readonly ) }}">
  </paper-icon-button>

  <paper-input id="input" value="{{ value }}" hidden$="{{ _hideButtons( myValue, readonly ) }}">
  </paper-input>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <paper-button on-tap='_myValue' rised style="background-color:blue; color:white">Hide/Show<Paper-button>
</template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```